# How to show the contents of an array correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I'm  trying to make a test correction simulator, that the user enters the test feedback at first an then the numbers of students in the class, the name and finally the answers.But the problem is: when I try to show the student names and the answer...they are below the other.So how I can fix this?

This problem is because i'm making two `for's` instead of one?So i can't display the student names and the answer correctly?

And my other problem is the score of the students.How I make it for each student and show it on the side.

Check my Stack trace below for a better understanding:

[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int score = 0, n, i, j = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n");

        System.out.print("How many students in the class?: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        String name[] = new String[n];
        char answer[][] = new char[n][5];
        float media[] = new float[n];
        char testFeedback[] = new char[5];
        int socreArray[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("--Type (a,b,c,d or e)--");
        for (int g = 0; g < testFeedback.length; g++) {
            System.out.print("TestFeedback | question[" + g + "]: ");
            testFeedback[g] = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Student name: ");
            name[i] = sc.next();

            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.println("answer nº" + (j + 1) + ": ");
                answer[i][j] = sc.next().charAt(0);

                if (answer[i][j] == testFeedback[j]) {

                    score++;
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Score: " + score);

        }

        System.out.println("\nGeneral report: ");
        System.out.println("Student - answer - score");

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(name[i]);

        }

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.println(answer[j]);

        }

        if (score > 3) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you went well!");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Too bad, you need to study more.");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correct, to show names and answer you could use 1 for:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     System.out.print(name[i] + ": ");
     for(int j = 0; j < answer[i].length; j++) {
         System.out.print(answer[i][j] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();

}
```

To show score, you have to store it somewhere, for example in anotherarray or list.

Comment: Ok the answer are now at the names side, but in this strange format `General report:  
Student - answer - score
Steve: [C@a298b7
Carlos: [C@14991ad`

Comment: And I have an warning saying**must explicitly convert the char[] to a String**

Comment: Edit answer according to your comment

Answer (score 1):

You need a string builder in your for loop above the System.out.println( "General Report" );
You don't need the next two for loops. Move the

```
System.out.println( "General Report" );
System.out.println( "Student - answer - score " );
```

above this loop. 
and move `if ( score > 3) else`  inside your loop as in below code. You can delete everything after this loop.

```
     System.out.println("\nGeneral report: ");
     System.out.println("Student - answer - score");

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.print("Student name: ");
            name[i] = sc.next();

            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.println("answer nº" + (j + 1) + ": ");
                answer[i][j] = sc.next().charAt(0);
                sb.append( String.valueOf(answer[i][j]) );
                if (answer[i][j] == testFeedback[j]) {

                    score++;
                }

            }
            System.out.println( name[i] + " - " + sb.toString() + " - " + score );
            if (score > 3) {
               System.out.println("Congratulations, you went well!");

            } else {
               System.out.println("Too bad, you need to study more.");
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the problem is that you're outputting the students in a loop THEN you're outputting the answers in another loop. This should happen in the same loop so that you output a student and their answers in the same loop cycle.

Given that your student array and answer array are the same size (each student has a corresponding answer at the same index), you could do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(student[i]);
    System.out.println(answer[i]);
}
```

Storing data in two parallel arrays is a bit awkward because you have to make sure that you update them together. This would be a good time to think about using some extra classes to represent the entities in your project and keep related things together.